# Camera App Crash at start

Tags: android, camera, crash

Hello i'm trying to build custom camera app following the android developer guides. The code is clean  with no errors, i followed the guide step to step but when i start the app it crash. i'm using the deprecated camera api.

this is the code of my own SurfaceView called CameraPreview

```
package guide.android.cameraappandroidguide;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import java.io.IOException;


public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private static final String TAG = "Error";

private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
private android.hardware.Camera mCamera;


public CameraPreview(Context context,android.hardware.Camera mCamera) {
    super(context);
    this.mCamera = mCamera;

    mHolder = getHolder();
    mHolder.addCallback(this);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
        Log.e("Surface creata","Ottimo");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG,"Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    if(mHolder.getSurface()==null){
        return;
    }

    try {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"Error setting camera preview: "+e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG,"Error setting preview: "+e.getMessage());
    }


}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
}
```

This is my MainActivity

```
package guide.android.cameraappandroidguide;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this,mCamera);

    FrameLayout frameLayoutPreview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_preview);
    frameLayoutPreview.addView(mCameraPreview);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseCamera();
}


public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c= null;
    //Proviamo ad aprire la Camera
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Error","Can't open th camera device");
    }
    return c;
};

public void releaseCamera(){
    if(mCamera!=null){
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera=null;
    }

}

}
```

This is my LogCat.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UunMj.png)

The app crash at start, i cant understand what's the problem..
Anyone can help me to understand how i can find the error using logcat or other debugging methods?

Thank you

Comment: can you share your manifest ?

Comment: in manifest i've declared uses-permission for camera..in any case, i've fixed  thank to @chengsam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add this line:

```
mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
```

after this:

```
mHolder = getHolder();
mHolder.addCallback(this);
```